# Enabling export of GCP billing pricing data to BigQuery gives security warning: This app isn't verified (gstatic)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to activate the export of GCP billing data to BigQuery. The BigQuery Data Transfer Service API is enabled in my target project and I have created a BigQuery dataset in the same project. There are two data exports that can be enabled: "Daily cost detail" data and "Pricing" data. Enabling "Daily cost detail" data export was successful, so I think that the basic setup is fine.

However, when I try to activate the "Pricing" data export with the same settings, something strange happens. I configure the target project and target BigQuery datastore and click "Save". Previously, for "daily cost detail", the process was finished here. But for "pricing", now a popup window opens, asking me to re-authenticate with my Google account. Once I do that, I receive a warning stating that "This app isn't verified" and "This app hasn't been verified by Google yet.", referring to "gstatic":

[Screenshot of the warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tPgp.png)

I'm unsure if something is going wrong here, because I never got this popup when enabling the daily cost detail export. And it seems strange that this integral function wouldn't be verified by Google itself. A colleague of mine tried to activate the pricing data export with their user account but the same thing happens. I talked to a Google representative in the support chat but they told me that this is out of their scope.

Is this warning supposed to happen when enabling the export of pricing data to BigQuery? Have others received the same warning? Is it safe to proceed?

Comment: I am unsure as if this is due to the export, however, I believe that this can be addressed by simply verifying your application by following [these instructions](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I would understand, but in this case it's an integral Google / GCP functionality, at least from my perspective. I think noone but Google would be able to verify their own application. This is also the reason why we're confused and wary about this warning.